# groupby for pandas data frame gives wrong results

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, stata, logarithm

I am trying to replicate a paper whose code was written in Stata for my course project using Python. I have difficulty replicating the results from a collapse command in their do-file. The corresponding line in the do-file is

```
collapse lexptot, by(clwpop right)
```

while I have

```
df.groupby(['cwpop', 'right'])['lexptot'].agg(['mean'])
```

The `lexptot` variable is the logarithm of a variable '`exptot`' which I calculated previously using `np.log(dfs['exptot])`.

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here? The means I calculate are typically around 1.5 higher than the means calculated in Stata.

Comment: add an example with the data please, and let the readers of your question be able to replicate the problem (if there is one)

Comment: Among many details here are quite what logarithm means. `np.log()` in Python is evidently natural logarithm: in Stata either `log()` or `ln()` is equivalent. .

Answer (score 1):

Once you update the question with more relevant details maybe I can answer more. But this is what I think might help you!

```
df.groupby(['cwpop', 'right']).mean()['lexptot']
```